# Vtiger Override Modules and Core Codes

Tags: php, crm, vtiger

How to override Vtiger modules and core codes to ensure that the future updates will still work? Do I need to create a subclass of a module and then extend the original class? Where do I put the new file (if there is a need to create a new one)?

Comment: have you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

i think the better way to create your own module, without change core files. Because in any future update it may be overwritten.
See this link to create custom module:
[Create custom module in vtiger](https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/CreatingEntityModule)